# file.getFileName().endsWith() not detecting .mp3

Tags: java

I'm probably missing something small, but I could not find it. using file.getFileName().endsWith(".mp3"), the boolean is always false. If I rename te files to *.mp and change the code to endsWith(".mp"), they are found. What happens here?

Greetings,
Jelmew

Edit: File is a Path object btw.

Filenames:

```
/home/jelmer/Music/01 - Nightwish - Shudder Before The Beautiful.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/02 - Nightwish - Weak Fantasy.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/03 - Elan (Album Version).mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/04- Nightwish - Yours Is An Empty Hope.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/05 - Nightwish - Our Decades In The Sun.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/06 - Nightwish - My Walden.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/07 - Nightwish - Endless Forms Most Beautiful.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/08 - Nightwish - Edema Ruh.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/09 - Nightwish - Alpenglow.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/10 - Nightwish - Eyes Of Sharbat Gula.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/11 - Nightwish - The Greatest Show on Earth.mp3
/home/jelmer/Music/test.mp3


public class mp3Walker extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if(file.getFileName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }
        System.out.println("done with file: "+file.getFileName());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        mp3Walker walker= new mp3Walker();
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("/home/jelmer/Music/"), walker);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
done with file: 07 - Nightwish - Endless Forms Most Beautiful.mp3
done with file: test.mp3
done with file: 08 - Nightwish - Edema Ruh.mp3
done with file: 05 - Nightwish - Our Decades In The Sun.mp3
done with file: 02 - Nightwish - Weak Fantasy.mp3
done with file: 11 - Nightwish - The Greatest Show on Earth.mp3
done with file: 01 - Nightwish - Shudder Before The Beautiful.mp3
done with file: 10 - Nightwish - Eyes Of Sharbat Gula.mp3
done with file: 04- Nightwish - Yours Is An Empty Hope.mp3
done with file: 06 - Nightwish - My Walden.mp3
done with file: 03 - Elan (Album Version).mp3
done with file: 09 - Nightwish - Alpenglow.mp3
```

Comment: provide some code... what kind of file? Javas `java.io.File` doesn't have a method called `getFileName()`...

Comment: @ParkerHalo `Path` class in java nio

Comment: @ParkerHalo `Paths.get()`. This is 2015. `File` is obsolete.

Comment: @fge This is 2015 and people are still asking about `java.util.Date`. It's not unreasonable to assume that a variable called `file` is a `File`.

Comment: @ParkerHalo i meant interface sorry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `Path`'s `.endsWith()` expects a *full* element of the path.

That is:

```
Paths.get("foo").endsWith("oo")
```

is equivalent to:

```
Paths.get("foo").endsWith(Paths.get("oo"))
```

which always returns false.

You want to test on the string value of the filename:

```
path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Path.getFileName() gives a Path object - not a String, as you might expect.
And Path.endsWith(String):

> tests if this path ends with a "Path", constructed by converting the given path string, in exactly the manner specified by the "endsWith(Path)" method. On UNIX for example, the path "foo/bar" ends with "foo/bar" and "bar". It does not end with "r" or "/bar"

Maybe you need to work on the "toString" representation:

file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".mp3")